Is this diagram in the Bosch manual wrong?
I am reading the Bosch router manual and am a bit confused with one of its diagrams.
This first diagram makes sense.  The router will tend to walk to the left of the feed direction (because the bit rotates clockwise) so the guide will continue to be flush against the workpiece causing the cut line to be straight.

This second diagram confuses me.  I would imagine the router to walk left of the feed direction again (because the bit rotates clockwise) so the router will move away from the board guide and no longer be flush causing the cut line to no longer be straight.

Am I misunderstanding something?  Does the router not walk left of the feed direction because the bit rotates clockwise?
Any clarification to this newbie will be greatly appreciated 
Thank you and have a wonderful day 

The standard advice or golden rule for feed direction should be followed almost always and that's not the case in Fig. 15. The fence should be to the left of the router relative to the feed direction:

So in terms of general advice for milling a groove or dado, yes the second diagram is wrong.

Thank you @Graphus for confirming
